# How to set storm worker's JVM max heap size?

Tags: java, jvm, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm new to Storm programming and I've got a job to do a test on a custom grouping method to see if it's better or not.

So I have to measure the storm's throughput on several different conditions such as different worker numbers, different worker memory..etc

It's easy to set the worker number using `conf.setNumWorkers();`, however I find it hard to set each worker's max heap size.

I tried editing `storm.yaml` and added

```
worker.childopts: "-Xmn128m-Xms128m-Xmx128m"
```

with

```
conf.put(Config.WORKER_CHILDOPTS, "-Xmn128m -Xms128m -Xmx128m");
```

added to my code.

However when I use `jmap -heap [pid]` on my worker node, I found the max heap size is still 768m which is the default max heap size.

How can I achieve such purpose to restrain the JVM's max memory use?

BTW, I'm using kafkaspout to send messages to storm, any sorts of suggestions on my testing work is welcomed.

Comment: did you find how can you make it ?

Comment: @user5520049 No, I didn't find the correct way to do, however I used an alternative way to put an restraint on memory by implementing our own spout, then fail the tuple in worker bolt if it reached the limit set by us. I can post the details if you are interested.

Comment: can you please post it ? thanks in advance

Comment: @user5520049 I posted an answer about my method, hope that helps.Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Although ssadaquat's answer is correct, and you can set the worker memory in storm's yaml file, I have been able to successfully do it programmatically like this:

```
Config stormConfig = new Config();
int fourGB = 4 * 1024;
stormConfig.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_MAX_HEAP_SIZE_MB, fourGB);
```

Doing it this way is especially helpful if you don't want to be bothered with changing the yaml file in multiple servers or if you don't want to be bothered with changing the yaml file at all.

There are many answers that say you have to set `childopts` to increase the memory, but that didn't work for me. In fact, I noticed that after I set `topology_worker_max_heap_size_mb`, the `childopts` value increases automatically. Also try to ensure that you have [enough of swap memory](http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2017/02/avoiding-memory-problems-when-working.html) on the server, especially when working with large amounts of data.

Comment: this does not work for me, the worker still have the same memory..

Answer (score 2):

Try editing storm/default.yaml file. Look for worker settings and there you will find the entry for setting heap memory. It should look like this by default!

```
worker.heap.memory.mb: 768
```

In the same file, you'll also find the following settings where you can change the values as per your need.

```
topology.component.resources.onheap.memory.mb: 128.0
topology.component.resources.offheap.memory.mb: 0.0
topology.component.cpu.pcore.percent: 10.0
topology.worker.max.heap.size.mb: 768.0
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did what you said, however `jmap -heap` still give me 768mb of max heap size :(  what version of storm were you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

If your Storm version is <1.0.0 you have to set worker.childopts in storm.yaml, and restart your supervisors. This parameter will not be pulled in as a topology-specific option [from what I've gleaned](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201503.mbox/%3CCAPbY5A48H_LgwHx3eKQyO2OEV3SfeFrkdbJCCPoyfM6QMutZeg@mail.gmail.com%3E), so the topology config change you did, will not affect the result.

For Storm version >=1.0.0, you can refer to [ssadaqat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37393681/6320293), but instead of editing defaults.yaml (which is part fo the source code), you again need to insert this value into storm.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the worker's max heap size by followings steps:

1: add "worker.heap.memory.mb: 2048" into nimbus node's conf/storm.yaml file;

2: restart nimbus and supervisor

the workers' heap size will be changed into 2GB

Comment: This does not appear to work with storm 0.10.0 - the default 768m are still used. This is after restarting nimbus, workers and topology, and distributing worker.heap.memory.mb: 2048 to all storm nodes. This post to the storm user list indicates similar behaviour (for some versions at least) https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201503.mbox/%3CCAPbY5A48H_LgwHx3eKQyO2OEV3SfeFrkdbJCCPoyfM6QMutZeg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: I just checked the source, and indeed that optioin only works in Storm>1.0.0, before that worker.childopts have to be eplicitely set

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out the correct way to set JVM's max heap size anyhow, but I used another method as a workaround.

**Note:** I currently don't have the source code in hand so the following code is just to demonstrate the idea and totally untested.

The method is to take advantage from the mechanism of re-transmitting failed tuples in Storm.

If you are using some sort of existed spout such as `KafkaSpout` or anything else then you don't have to worry about re-transmitting failed tuples, it's all taken care of by default implementations.

However if you are implementing your own spout you have to do it on your own. I believe that if you're trying to implement the spout you must have known the `void ack(Object msgId)` and `void fail(Object msgId)` etc. and it's easy to implement the re-transmitting mechanism.

And our WorkerBolt will look like this, assuming it's a word count bolt.

```
class WorkerBolt implements IRichBolt{
    ...
    private HashMap<String, int> counts = new HashMap<>();
    private int wordStoredCount = 0;
    private final int COUNT_LIMIT = 500000;  // Here's our limit
    ...
    void execute(Tuple tuple){
        if(wordStoreCount >= COUNT_LIMIT){
            tuple.fail();
        }

        // do our counting stuff

        wordStoredCount++;

        // send the tuple downstream to aggregate/process/etc. if needed
    }
    ...
```

It's not very accurate because each word may have different length or size, you can use `MEMORY_COUNT` `memoryStoredCount` and add up each word's memory use to `memoryStoredCount` to be more accurate.

Adopting this method makes the system more controllable because if we set the max heap size and the JVM reaches the bound it will simply throw a OutOfMemoryException and shutdown the system, which may not be what we wanted in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , my problem with reading size of worker.childopts because it be readen with another number , the basic problem i have is OOM "GC overhead limit exceed" i'm trying to increase size of worker and increasing didn't be readen as i wrote .